# What's the same domain in access-control-allow-origin

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have an error in IE and it's `origin not found in access-control-allow-origin header`, which works well in Chrome.

I used Ajax to visit the url under this domain.

Finally, I found that it's because the url in address bar. If I enter `aa.com` in Chrome, it's turned to `http://www.aa.com`, but in IE, it's `http://aa.com`.

This is where I don't get. Didn't they have the same domain (`aa.com`)? Why does this error occur?

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Origin simply isn't based on the domain.

> Two pages have the same origin if the protocol, port (if one is specified), and host are the same for both pages.

— [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

---

Avoid hosting the same site on multiple hostnames. It has many drawbacks. Pick one of them to be canonical and redirect all the others to it.

Try to use relative URLs instead of absolute ones too.

---

> Finally, I found that it's because the url in address bar. If I enter aa.com in Chrome, it's turned to `http://www.aa.com`, but in IE, it's `http://aa.com`.

That isn't normal behaviour. They are most likely autocompleting different URLs from your history, and not changing what you are actually typing.

Comment: Then for my case, what's the difference? host?

Comment: Yes. They have different hostnames.

Comment: Thanks, Quentin. But can't the 'www' be left out?

Comment: @Sky — Leaving out the `www.` gives you a different origin, and a different (although possibly identical) site (as far as everything outside of the HTTP server is concerned at least).

Comment: @Sky: From the browser's point of view, `www` is part of the domain. The browser really has a very simple understanding of domains that's not the same as human understanding. That allows browsers a simple way to process US domains (.com) and domains of other countries (.com.country_code). Otherwise all websites in other countries would be considered a single domain (for example google.com.my and amazon.com.my). There's nothing special about `www` it's just a string.